# The email address is badly formatted Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

hi i am working on a android project where i am using firebase as back-end and i am building a signup and login form . When ever i sign up the code is working well and . When i try to retrieve it using "`signInWithEmailAndPassword` i am getting the fallowing error. **The email address is badly formatted Firebase**`

login Activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mLoginEmailField;
    private EditText mloginPassField;

    private Button mLoginbtn;
    private Button mNewAccountbtn;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRefrence;





    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mLoginEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmailField);
        mloginPassField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPasswordField);

        mLoginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mNewAccountbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newAccountbtn);
        mDatabaseRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        mNewAccountbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent rigisterIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RigisterActivity.class);
                rigisterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(rigisterIntent);
            }
        });


        mLoginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    private void CheckLogin() {

        String email = mloginPassField.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = mloginPassField.getText().toString().trim();


        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){


            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        CheackUserExsists();
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Sign-in Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Erorr Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

    private void CheackUserExsists() {

     final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabaseRefrence.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){

                    Intent MainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    MainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(MainIntent);
                }else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"You need to setup your Account.. ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Rigister Actvity

```
public class RigisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mNameField;
    private EditText mPassField;
    private EditText mEmailField;

    private Button mRigisterbtn;

    private ProgressDialog mProgres;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rigister);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mProgres = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameField);
        mPassField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passFiled);
        mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);

        mRigisterbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rigisterbtn);

        mRigisterbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StartRigister();
            }
        });

    }

    private void StartRigister() {

        final String name = mNameField.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = mPassField.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString().trim();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){

            mProgres.setMessage("Signing Up... ");
            mProgres.show();

               mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                       if(task.isSuccessful()){
                         String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                           DatabaseReference CurentUser_db =  mDatabase.child(user_id);
                           CurentUser_db.child("name").setValue(name);
                           CurentUser_db.child("image").setValue("defalut");
                        mProgres.dismiss();
                           Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RigisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                           mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                           startActivity(mainIntent);
                       }

                   }
               });

        }


    }
}
```

I have made sure that i have  setup email and password active in the auth section of firebase.

still firebase giving me the following error.

Comment: The error message is correct. The format of the email address isn't valid. So natually, we need to know the email address being used to offer even a clue why. A better [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be to just hard code the actual values that cause the error and get rid of all this superfluous UI-related code that isn't related to your problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your code to set `email` is incorrect. You are setting `email` to the value of the  `EditText` for `password`.

In method `CheckLogin()`, change:

```
String email = mloginPassField.getText().toString().trim();
```

to:

```
String email = mLoginEmailField .getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: This was my exact issue. Graçias.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use Edittext named as Email and Password you need not do anything.
the error comes up only if you use plaintext for both...

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem recently, possible solutions are :

1. Check the inputType of your EditText Field.

ADD this attribute to your EditText

```
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

2. In Activity class, it should look like if u are using TextInputLayout instead of editText

   ```
           mDisplayName=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
           mDisplayEmail=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
           mDisplayPassword=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);


           String name = mDisplayName.getEditText().getText().toString();
           String email = mDisplayEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
           String password = mDisplayPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();`
   ```

Answer (score 2):

**Remove whitespaces** from email text it worked for me. by using `trim()` method you can remove spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The error popped for me due to my silly action of using "tab" to go to the next text field. Don't use "tab" for it, instead use your mouse to move to the next text field. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me resolve this issue is to put the `android:id` into the correct place.
If you are using Material design, there are two parts of your text input, the layout and the actual functional part.
If you put the ID into the layout, you'll only be able to access `editText` property in the activity class, but if you put it in the functional part, you'll be able to access `.text` or `getText()` as someone above has stated.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String pass = mloginPassField.getText().toString().trim(); 
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)
```

to

```
String password = mloginPassField.getText().toString().trim();
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, whenever you add a code, enclose it within ` ... `

Answer (score 0):

Your code to set email is incorrect.
Perhaps a space was used as the last letter.

```
  final User? user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _emailController.text.toString().trim(),
    password: _passwordController.text,
  )).user;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you may write that `mailAdress.toString()` , you can change as

```
mailAdress.**text**.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me :)

createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
email: email.toString().trim(),
password: password,
);