# Firebase Authentication won't create an account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know what's wrong with my code or firebase console, but when I run the app and click the submit button to try and create an account it runs the `.addOnFailureListener` and I can't figure out why.

Sorry for the vague description, but I'll be really thankful if anyone can tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private TextView mTextMessage;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;

@Override
@TargetApi(24)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account_page);

                //creating user if all previous data validation checks out
                if (nextPage == true) {mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userInputArrayList.get(1), userInputArrayList.get(2)).addOnCompleteListener(CreateAccountPage.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"9");
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                Log.d(TAG,"Sign up Successful");
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                updateUI(user, userInputArrayList, tglBtnAdmin);
                            } else {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                showToast("Could not create an account, please try again later.");
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            showToast("Account could not be created, please try again later");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                showToast("Please fill all fields.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Error Message

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The email address is badly formatted.
at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdr.zzb(Unknown Source:30)
at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeu.zza(Unknown Source:16)
at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzc(Unknown Source:33)
at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.onFailure(Unknown Source:49)
at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:18)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

Comment: Can you log the exception that is being passed in the onFailureListener? The error you gave is not very descriptive.

Comment: @doug Sorry, I have edited it to show the correct error. I'm still not sure what I should do though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664910/the-email-address-is-badly-formatted-firebase

Check this link

Comment: The error message says "The email address is badly formatted."  What do you think that means?

Comment: @Dipin Thank you! I did the same thing and set the wrong number for the array list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the instances of the classes inside the onCreate method and then try.And if this won't work,post the correct error stack trace.Through this,we cannot identify the error where its happening and why.

Stack trace is showing that email is badly formatted.That means,you are entering invalid email address or which is not correctly formatted.Make sure you enter the correct address.Try checking with your original email  address and debug and check what value it is taking input.Feel free to comment.

In the userInputArrayList,you are getting email and password.I assume that there are only two fields you are storing in that arraylist.arrayList starts from '0' programatically.so,try entering get(0) for email  and get(1) for password.Hope this helps